# Launchrock widget

Tags: widget, launch

I am using launchrock widget on my website and doen't work.Javascript is loading successfully still it not working.Following is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//mywidget.js"></script>
<div id="lr-widget" rel="R34FGD"></div>
```

Any suggestion.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Switch the lines order. The script needs to be loaded after the div tag.